# Masking a Drawable/Bitmap on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, mask, drawable

I'm currently looking for a way to use a black and white bitmap to mask the alpha channel of another bitmap or Drawable on Android.  I'm curious as to what the best way to do this is.  I certainly have a couple of ideas for how to do this, but they are not optimal.

I need to be able to apply a new mask to the image every so often (the black and white bitmap will change every few seconds).

Any feedback on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to use the black portions of the mask bitmap to set the alpha channel of the corresponding pixel on the other bitmap/Drawable to 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution is close to @over_optimistic's solution, less one saveLayer() call. I use a Drawable mask instead of a path, in my case it was a disc.

I declared these variables as fields (it's good practice to allocate memory outside of onDraw method):

```
private Paint maskingPaint = new Paint();
private Drawable mask = <insert your drawable here>
```

Then, somewhere outside of onDraw(), setup the objects:

```
// Xfermode won't work if hardware accelerated
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

// Using destination shape as a mask
// For a good explanation of PorterDuff transfer modes : http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html
maskingPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
maskingPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

// Position the mask
mask.setBounds(<insert your mask bounds here>);
```

Then finally, the onDraw() method applies the mask:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Draw the mask first, making it the PorterDuff destination
    mask.draw(canvas);

    // Save the layer with the masking paint, that will be applied on restore()
    // Using CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG to avoid any overflow of the masked image outside the mask bounds.
    Rect bounds = mask.getBounds();
    canvas.saveLayer(bounds.left, bounds.top, bounds.right, bounds.bottom, maskingPaint, 
            Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

    // Draw the shape offscreen, making it the PorterDuff source
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Apply the source to the destination, using SRC_IN transfer mode
    canvas.restore();
}
```

For a better understanding of the transfer modes, I referred to http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html.
That page is pretty interesting to read. After that, with the same kind of code you'll be able to acheive much more than a simple mask!

Comment: Perfect solution. Others are a bit too long.

Comment: IMO better than the accepted answer, I prefer drawable over path

Answer (score 6):

I got it working, so it's something like this

```
    // we first same the layer, rectF is the area of interest we plan on drawing
    // this will create an offscreen bitmap
    canvas.saveLayer(rectF, null, Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG
            | Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
            | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
            | Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);

    // draw our unmasked stuff
    super.draw(canvas);
    // We same a layer again but this time we pass a paint object to mask
    // the above layer
    maskPaint = new Paint()
    maskPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));

    canvas.saveLayer(rectF, maskPaint,
            Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG
                    | Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
                    | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG
                    | Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
    // we draw the mask which is black and white. In my case
    // I have a path, and I use a blurPaint which blurs the mask slightly
    // You can do anti aliasing or whatever you which. Just black & white
    canvas.drawPath(path, blurPaint);
    // We restore twice, this merges the results upward
    // as each saveLayer() allocates a new drawing bitmap
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.restore();
```

Comment: If overriding onDraw method, instead of `super.draw(canvas)` there should be `super.onDraw(canvas)`. Otherwise you end up in endless loop with StackOverflow error.

Comment: I did the same thing as above in the `onDraw` of my custom view, but it seems that `saveLayer` is expensive and hence instead of that I set a hardware layer to my view (`View.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint)`). More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33483016/4747587

Answer (score 4):

I made a maskable layout.
It's a framelayout where you can specifiy the xporterduffmode and the mask.
You  can find it here: https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're going for, but I believe that a combination of [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) and  [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) may work.  BitmapDrawable will allow you to use your Bitmaps as Drawables, and then you can use LayerDrawable to layer the mask on top of another Drawable.

Comment: this will not work if you want the masked part to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Xfermodes example in the API Demo I was able to use a PorterDuffXfermode applied to a Paint object to blend together two bitmaps on a canvas.  This works exactly how I need it to.

Comment: Could you add more details?