# drawing non rectangular shapes on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am try to implement this shape with android xml drawables:

[image]

I am able to get the rectangle but I can figure out to get the triangle tip. I also need to apply a gradient to this shape.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think leveraging XML drawables is to create a clipping-mask via 9-patch drawable and then project that onto a rectangle drawable.

This probably will require a custom drawable class though. I searched and found that this Q/A might solve that part of the problem. [Masking a Drawable/Bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623888/masking-a-drawable-bitmap-on-android)

Looking at the SDK docs [`ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) implies that it would help with that but it turns out that it might be a poorly named class. It doesn't do what I thought it would.

The easier way to accomplish this is to just create a 9-patch out of the object itself. You lose the gradient flexibility unfortunately when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9-patch to draw it.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

just crop a little path around with triangle tips and make 9-patch like this [check this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4kPv.png) and then use drawable shape to draw your gradient on top of it.