# Android circular image view using xml

Tags: android

Here is the drawable layout code "round_button.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="ring">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#E6E6E6" />
<corners android:radius="30dip"/>
</shape>
```

Here is the imageview code

```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/round_button"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
   android:src="@drawable/menu1" />
```

But i dint get the rounded imageview

Comment: It may be more efficient to handle the view dynamically by creating a class that extends imageview and handling the drawing of the image ondraw

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your example code, you're expecting the `background` of the `ImageView` to act as a mask for the `src`.

When you define a `src` for an `ImageView`, that is what's going to be displayed. You're going to need to work a bit harder to define any image the `ImageView` gets as a circle.

Here's a link to how to work with masks in Android:
[Masking a Drawable/Bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623888/masking-a-drawable-bitmap-on-android)

Comment: No not like mask,i'm trying to define a rounded circle inside that i want to place my image so that the ImageView looks like rounded