# Android Bitmap Masking (Xfermode) leaves opaque black background behind

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-bitmap

I have a custom view and in the `onDraw()`, I am trying to perform bitmap masking. I have a `squareBitmap` (red color) which fills the whole view, and I have a `circleBitmap` (blue color) that acts as the mask. I am using the mode: `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN`.

The result I am expecting is a RED filled circle. I get that, but I also get a BLACK opaque background. I don't want this opaque background, rather it should be transparent. `Figure 1` is the result I got, and `Figure 2` is the result that I am looking for.

[image: Figure 1 : The Result I got] [image: Figure 2: The Result that I am looking for]

My code: (I have moved everything inside `onDraw()` for the purpose of this question)

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    final int width = canvas.getWidth();
    final int height = canvas.getHeight();

    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas circleCanvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    circleCanvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2, p);

    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    Bitmap squareBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas squareCanvas = new Canvas(squareBitmap);
    final Rect squareRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    squareCanvas.drawRect(squareRect, p);

    Paint q = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(squareBitmap, 0, 0, q);
    q.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, 0, 0, q);
    q.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I avoid this black opaque background?

Comment: Try `DST_OUT` instead of `DST_IN`. Or `SRC_IN`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No, it's not working. Now I get the black filled circle and a red background. The background is red because of the `squareBitmap`, but why is the circle  black? Ideally, the circle should be transparent and hence should be blue (the color of the background layout).

Comment: You should find an answer here: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thank you, but this link gives an idea on how the blending modes work, but didn't explain about the fix for my problem. I finally fixed by problem by setting a hardware layer to my custom view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that to get the `Xfermode` done, I need to redirect the drawing to an offscreen bitmap. So adding the following fixed my problem.

```
canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), q);
```

But then again, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) of `saveLayer` says to avoid using this method since it is expensive. It is suggested to use a [harware layer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE) instead of this method.

> Avoid using this method, especially if the bounds provided are large,
>   or if the CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG is omitted from the saveFlags
>   parameter. It is recommended to use a hardware layer on a View to
>   apply an xfermode, color filter, or alpha, as it will perform much
>   better than this method.

Hence, intead of `saveLayer` method, I was able to fix it by adding the following:

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, q);
```

Comment: would you mind providing the complete example, that shows drawing bitmap, mask and the used paint and XferMode? Thanks!

Comment: The code in my question is the complete example. I have a class that `extends View`. And i have the 'onDraw()' method that which I have in the question. The only thing that i added to make it work is in the answer: 'setLayerType'. You might wanna take a look at this for a real world scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33483600/4747587